# UE4 Editor crashing with "EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION writing address" error

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm trying to create a 3D board game in UE 4.26.2 and one morning my project just started crashing the editor every time I opened it, yet it was working fine the night before. The error message is `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION writing address 0x0000000000000008`. I've managed to narrow down the problem and re-create it in a blank project, but I'm still not sure why its happening. The code works fine when I create it, but as soon as I close the project and re-open it, it crashes.

**How to replicate the problem**

1. Create an empty BluePrint project
2. Create two blueprints, both derived from `Actor`, named `BP_TileMap` and `BP_Tile`
3. Create a child class from `BP_Tile` named `BP_Tile_A`
4. Create two structures named `BoardLayout` and `LayoutRow`
5. In `LayoutRow` create one variable named `Column` with the type set to an `Array` of `BP_Tile -> Class Reference`
6. Add a few default values and leave them set to `None`
7. In `BoardLayout` create one variable named `Row` with the type set to an `Array` of `LayoutRow`
8. Add two default values and set each of the `Column` values to `BP_Tile_A`
9. In `BP_Tile` create a variable named `TileMap`, set its type to a `BP_TileMap` reference and make it instance editable and exposed on spawn
10. In `BP_TileMap` create a variable named `Tiles` with the type set to an `Array` of `BP_Tile`
11. Then create a variable named `Layout` with its type set to `BoardLayout`
12. Next create a function called `ResetMap` and enable call in editor
13. Copy the graph below which loops through the `Column`'s in each `Row` of the `BoardLayout`, spawns the referenced class (I.e. `BP_Tile_A`), sets the new tile's `TileMap` to `self` and adds it to the `Tiles` array.

[image: BP_TileMap->ResetMap Graph]

14. Drag a `BP_TileMap` into the default level and run the `ResetMap` function from the details panel.

The result should look like below, which as you can see works fine. But if you save and close the project at this point, it will crash the next time you open the project.

[image: Result of function]

My guess is that its trying to access an object which hasn't been loaded into memory yet when opening the project, and that the object was already in memory when I first created it, hence the function working initially? But I can't figure out why or what I need to change to fix it.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Stack Trace (with symbols installed)**

```
Unhandled Exception: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION writing address 0x0000000000000008

UE4Editor_CoreUObject!UObjectBase::UObjectBase() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectBase.cpp:109]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!StaticAllocateObject() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectGlobals.cpp:2500]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!UClass::CreateDefaultObject() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\Class.cpp:3689]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::CreateExport() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:4707]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::CreateExportAndPreload() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3482]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::LoadAllObjects() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3647]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!LoadPackageInternal() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectGlobals.cpp:1343]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!<lambda_35e7e9d57300e3e17d738623778b7fa6>::operator()() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3033]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImportInner() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3126]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImport() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2790]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImportInner() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3154]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImport() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2790]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::CreateImport() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:4987]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::ResolveDependencyPlaceholder() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\Blueprint\BlueprintSupport.cpp:1577]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::ResolveDeferredDependencies() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\Blueprint\BlueprintSupport.cpp:1328]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::ResolveDeferredDependencies() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\Blueprint\BlueprintSupport.cpp:1454]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::Preload() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:4120]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::CreateExport() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:4830]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::CreateExportAndPreload() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3482]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::LoadAllObjects() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3647]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!LoadPackageInternal() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectGlobals.cpp:1343]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!LoadPackage() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectGlobals.cpp:1458]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!StaticLoadObjectInternal() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectGlobals.cpp:871]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!StaticLoadObject() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectGlobals.cpp:924]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FObjectPropertyBase::FindImportedObject() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\PropertyBaseObject.cpp:495]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FObjectPropertyBase::ParseObjectPropertyValue() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\PropertyBaseObject.cpp:336]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FObjectPropertyBase::ImportText_Internal() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\PropertyBaseObject.cpp:369]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FObjectProperty::ImportText_Internal() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\PropertyObject.cpp:142]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FClassProperty::ImportText_Internal() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\PropertyClass.cpp:100]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FArrayProperty::ImportTextInnerItem() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\PropertyArray.cpp:541]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FArrayProperty::ImportText_Internal() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\PropertyArray.cpp:502]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FProperty::ImportText() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Public\UObject\UnrealType.h:351]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FProperty::ImportSingleProperty() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\Property.cpp:1464]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!UScriptStruct::ImportText() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\Class.cpp:2812]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FStructProperty::ImportText_Internal() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\PropertyStruct.cpp:293]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FArrayProperty::ImportTextInnerItem() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\PropertyArray.cpp:541]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FArrayProperty::ImportText_Internal() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\PropertyArray.cpp:502]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FProperty::ImportText() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Public\UObject\UnrealType.h:351]
UE4Editor_UnrealEd!FBlueprintEditorUtils::PropertyValueFromString_Direct() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Editor\UnrealEd\Private\Kismet2\BlueprintEditorUtils.cpp:8819]
UE4Editor_UnrealEd!UUserDefinedStructEditorData::ReinitializeDefaultInstance() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Editor\UnrealEd\Private\UserDefinedStructEditorData.cpp:209]
UE4Editor_Engine!UUserDefinedStruct::Serialize() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Private\UserDefinedStruct.cpp:133]
UE4Editor_Engine!UUserDefinedStruct::Serialize() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Inc\Engine\UserDefinedStruct.gen.cpp:224]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::Preload() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:4073]
UE4Editor_Engine!UUserDefinedStruct::RecursivelyPreload() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Private\UserDefinedStruct.cpp:338]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!PreloadInnerStructMembers() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\PropertyStruct.cpp:31]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FStructProperty::Serialize() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\PropertyStruct.cpp:224]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!UStruct::SerializeProperties() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\Class.cpp:1760]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!UStruct::Serialize() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\Class.cpp:1865]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!UClass::Serialize() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\Class.cpp:4320]
UE4Editor_Engine!UBlueprintGeneratedClass::Serialize() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Private\BlueprintGeneratedClass.cpp:1725]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::Preload() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:4073]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::CreateExport() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:4830]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::CreateExportAndPreload() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3482]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::LoadAllObjects() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3647]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!LoadPackageInternal() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectGlobals.cpp:1343]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!<lambda_35e7e9d57300e3e17d738623778b7fa6>::operator()() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3033]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImportInner() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3126]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImport() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2790]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImportInner() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3154]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImport() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2790]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::CreateImport() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:4987]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::ResolveDependencyPlaceholder() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\Blueprint\BlueprintSupport.cpp:1577]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::ResolveDeferredDependencies() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\Blueprint\BlueprintSupport.cpp:1403]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::Preload() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:4120]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::CreateExport() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:4830]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::CreateExportAndPreload() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3482]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::LoadAllObjects() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3647]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!LoadPackageInternal() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectGlobals.cpp:1343]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!<lambda_35e7e9d57300e3e17d738623778b7fa6>::operator()() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3033]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImportInner() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3126]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImport() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2790]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImportInner() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3154]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImport() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2790]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::Verify() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2562]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::FinalizeCreation() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2405]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::Tick() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:808]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::CreateLinker() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:470]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!GetPackageLinker() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\Linker.cpp:815]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!LoadPackageInternal() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectGlobals.cpp:1234]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!<lambda_35e7e9d57300e3e17d738623778b7fa6>::operator()() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3033]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImportInner() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3126]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImport() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2790]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImportInner() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3154]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImport() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2790]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::Verify() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2562]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::FinalizeCreation() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2405]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::Tick() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:808]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::CreateLinker() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:470]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!GetPackageLinker() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\Linker.cpp:815]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!LoadPackageInternal() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectGlobals.cpp:1234]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!<lambda_35e7e9d57300e3e17d738623778b7fa6>::operator()() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3033]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImportInner() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3126]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImport() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2790]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImportInner() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3154]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImport() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2790]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::Verify() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2562]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::FinalizeCreation() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2405]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::Tick() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:808]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::CreateLinker() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:470]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!GetPackageLinker() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\Linker.cpp:815]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!LoadPackageInternal() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectGlobals.cpp:1234]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!<lambda_35e7e9d57300e3e17d738623778b7fa6>::operator()() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3033]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImportInner() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3126]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImport() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2790]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImportInner() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3154]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImport() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2790]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::Verify() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2562]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::FinalizeCreation() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2405]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::Tick() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:808]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::CreateLinker() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:470]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!GetPackageLinker() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\Linker.cpp:815]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!LoadPackageInternal() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectGlobals.cpp:1234]
UE4Editor_CoreUObject!LoadPackage() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectGlobals.cpp:1458]
UE4Editor_UnrealEd!UEditorEngine::Map_Load() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Editor\UnrealEd\Private\EditorServer.cpp:2664]
UE4Editor_UnrealEd!UEditorEngine::HandleMapCommand() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Editor\UnrealEd\Private\EditorServer.cpp:6204]
UE4Editor_UnrealEd!UEditorEngine::Exec() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Editor\UnrealEd\Private\EditorServer.cpp:5705]
UE4Editor_UnrealEd!UUnrealEdEngine::Exec() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Editor\UnrealEd\Private\UnrealEdSrv.cpp:697]
UE4Editor_UnrealEd!FEditorFileUtils::LoadMap() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Editor\UnrealEd\Private\FileHelpers.cpp:2554]
UE4Editor_UnrealEd!FEditorFileUtils::LoadDefaultMapAtStartup() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Editor\UnrealEd\Private\FileHelpers.cpp:4043]
UE4Editor_UnrealEd!FUnrealEdMisc::OnInit() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Editor\UnrealEd\Private\UnrealEdMisc.cpp:359]
UE4Editor_UnrealEd!EditorInit() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Editor\UnrealEd\Private\UnrealEdGlobals.cpp:115]
UE4Editor!GuardedMain() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Launch\Private\Launch.cpp:149]
UE4Editor!GuardedMainWrapper() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Launch\Private\Windows\LaunchWindows.cpp:137]
UE4Editor!WinMain() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Launch\Private\Windows\LaunchWindows.cpp:268]
UE4Editor!__scrt_common_main_seh() [d:\agent\_work\5\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:288]
kernel32
ntdll
```